# PopOver and Tableviews

Tags: cocoa-touch, tableview, dismiss, popover

Quick question on popovers, i seem not grasp a way of closing a popview when i select something from it (tableview)

so i have a list items on a tableview which popup using a UIPopoverController so when i select an item i'd like to the popove to fade away.

MainViewController

```
  - (IBAction)popoverFontName:(id)sender 
    CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[popoverFontName frame] 
                                       fromView:[popoverFontName superview]];
    TitleController *titleC=[[TitleController alloc]init];
    popup =[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:titleC];

    [popup presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [popup setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(50.0, 300.0)];

    [titleC release];

}
```

TitleController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *selectedLang = [titleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  

    //Initialize the detail view controller and display it.  
    MyDetViewCont *myDetViewCont = [[MyDetViewCont alloc] initWithNibName:@"myDetViewCont" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; // view controller instance  

}
```

On the title contoller i dont know how to dismiss the popover

Answer (score 0):

You can call dismissPopoverAnimated: on the popoverController. You should keep an instance of your popover as an instance variable in order to dismiss from the UITableViewDelegate methods.